# Add a variable inside a mysql query

Tags: php

I have a variable `$text = "sometexthere"`

I would like to add this variable `$text` inside the following mysql query instead of `sometexthere`

`$query = "SELECT sum(nbr) AS sum FROM table2 WHERE name LIKE '%sometexthere%'";`

I tried doing that in many ways like

`$query = "SELECT sum(stats) AS sum FROM download WHERE filename LIKE '%' . $text . '%'";`

and

```
$name = "'%' . $text . '%'";
$query = 'SELECT sum(stats) AS sum FROM download WHERE filename LIKE '.$name.'';
```

But not working :/

Comment: You've not googled for this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$query = "SELECT sum(stats) AS sum FROM download WHERE filename LIKE '%$text%'";
```

and avoid this line

```
$name = "'%' . $text . '%'";
```

or try like this,

```
$name = "%".$text."%";
$query = "SELECT sum(stats) AS sum FROM download WHERE filename LIKE '$name'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query = "SELECT sum(stats) AS sum FROM download WHERE filename LIKE '%" . $text . "%'";
```